# Is it ok to have a code base I submitted as part of a recruitment process peer reviewed here?

Tags: discussion

I think this question is quite meta.

As part of a recruitment process, I was asked to solve some programming problem. They thought my code wasn't up to their standards, but I feel like I need more context to their feedback (which companies don't really bother supplying more of), and I'd really love to have it peer reviewed here. In one previous correspondence, they asked me not to share the problems they asked me to solve, but there was no mention of not sharing my own solution.

Comment: If not for the fact that they asked you not to share the problem, it would be one of our many [tag:interview-questions].

Comment: A solution without stating the problem it solves would make a lousy question I'm afraid.

Comment: I think I can express that in a more general sense. I'm just really after other people reviewing my code because I feel like their review process was a bit unfair, so I'm really interested to see if other people outside their organization think the same way about my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wrote the code, you own the code, the code works (so far as you know) so it would be a perfectly On-Topic CR question.

Whether you *should* when you've been asked not to is a question of Ethics, Professionalism, possibly Law (if you signed an NDA or similar as part of the recruitment process) and specific to your particular situation. Such questions belong on [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've sent the recruiter an email asking for their opinion and/or consent. I never signed an NDA with them, so technically I'm not bound by law. However, I value professionalism as much as I value the quality of my code.

Comment: @PsychoPunch starting to read your comment, when I saw "I've sen the recruiter and email..." my mind was screaming *"No! You don't owe them that!"*. But your note about valuing professionalism was perfect, salient, and very respectful.